# Counter example to not surjective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have to provide a counter example to show that the function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where  $f(x) = x^2+4 $ is not surjective

Would making the function natural number into integer ie
$f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be an acceptable counter-example?

Comment: No that would be changing the subject :) And anyway it wouldn't help – $x \mapsto x^2 + 4 \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ isn't surjective either (same counterexample).

Comment: no but it is not injective...

Comment: $x^2+4$ is never equal to $1$.

Comment: That's correct, and good that you observed it. But doesn't help show it's not surjective: a function can be injective but not surjective, surjective but not injective, or both, or neither. This one's easy. If $x < y$ then is $f(x) \le f(y)$? What is $f(0)$? What is $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c\in\mathbb{N}$. Then for $x\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $f(x) = c$ if and only if $x^2 + 4 = c$ which is true if and only if $x^2 + 4 - c = 0$. This is a quadratic polynomial and you can find its roots explicitly. Can you find a value of $c\in\mathbb{N}$ for which there are no integer roots? Such a $c$ will be a counterexample, since you would have no element in your domain that maps to it, despite it being in your codomain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the domain of your function as you please. What you want to show is that there's some natural number $n$ which is not in the image of $f$ with inputs from the natural numbers, i.e. that there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k) \neq n$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here is a hint to help you find such a natural number: $x^{2} \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, so...

Comment: didnt think so. I came across a similar question not to long ago but the question was with Integers.

Comment: So if i plug any number greater than or equal to 0 it ends up not being not onto?

Comment: @Jkoz: do you know what it means for a function to be surjective? The point is that you can find an element in the target space $(\mathbb{N})$ which is not in the image set $f(\mathbb{N})$. In this case, $f(x) = x^{2}+4 \geqslant 4$ for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$, so in particular, $f(x) \neq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Is this clear?

Comment: Clearer now thank you.